# Add name from other table linked with primary ID key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables called Doctor, Appointment and Person. I need to add the name of the doctors to the following result:

[image]

Using this code:

```
SELECT doctor.doctor_id, COUNT(appointment.appt_time) AS No_APP 
FROM doctor
LEFT JOIN appointment 
ON appointment.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id
GROUP BY doctor.doctor_id;
```

What modification can I do to it so I can have the name of the doctor with it, here is a list of my Tables(the names are in the person table with their doctor_id):

[image]

Comment: next time sample data give in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Yeah, it's really hard for us to cut and paste from images.

Comment: You can't actually. You have no way to tie your doctor to the person table. The only thing you can do is modify the Doctor table to include a person_id column that you populate. Sorry.

Comment: @MikeC. I'll bet doctor_id and patient_id are both foreign keys to person.person_id.

Comment: You are probably correct! Good thinking.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    doctor.doctor_id,
    person.last_name,
    COUNT(appointment.appt_time) AS No_APP 
FROM
    doctor
LEFT JOIN
    appointment  ON appointment.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id
LEFT JOIN
    person  ON doctor.doctor_id = person.person_id
GROUP BY
    doctor.doctor_id,
    person.last_name;
```

Or you can even skip `doctor` table:

```
SELECT
    person.person_id,
    person.last_name,
    COUNT(appointment.appt_time) AS No_APP 
FROM
    person
LEFT JOIN
    appointment ON appointment.doctor_id = person.person_id
GROUP BY
    person.person_id,
    person.last_name;
```

Comment: Why a left join? Just in case a doctor is missing from the person table?